# Url rewriting not working in WAMP Subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, wamp, subdomain

I created a Subdomain under my WAMP server for mobile site and it uses IP address as the domain name which is `192.168.106.1`

But the issue is that when I try to rewrite a url in my `.htaccess` file, I doesn't work. And I use a duplicated `.htaccess` file which works for the `localhost`

Below is my server configuration for the domain name in my `httpd.conf` file

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.106.1>
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
# The name to respond to
ServerName m.localhost
# Folder where the files live
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/mobile/"
# A few helpful settings...
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/mobile/">
Allow from all
Order Allow,Deny
# Enables .htaccess files for this site
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
# Apache will look for these two files, in this order, if no file is specified in the URL
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

I also removed the comment tag on the second line but it still not working.

Please anyone with a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution

First make sure you go to your `C:/wamp/bin/apache/YOUR APACHE VERSION/conf` and open up your `httpd.conf` file and uncomment this line

```
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

So it will look like this

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Then also open up your `host` file located in `C:/windows/System32/drivers/etc` and add this (your ip address to the configuration)

```
#add the sub-domain name, in this case I use mobile, it can be anything
192.168.106.1   mobile.localhost
192.168.106.1   192.168.106.1
```

Then finally and most importantly, open up your `vhost` file in `C:/wamp/bin/apache/YOUR APACHE VERSION/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` and add this to the file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/mobile"
    ServerName m.localhost
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/mobile">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        #If you want to allow access from your internal network
        # For specific ip addresses add one line per ip address
        Allow from 192.168.106.1
        # For every ip in the subnet, just use the first 3 numbers of the subnet
        #Allow from 192.168.0
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then restart your WAMP server and it works